# MYSQL PDO and Stored Procedures in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was wondering if there is a way yet to call a stored mysql procedure with named parameters ? I saw there was a future request a long time ago but have not found anything on it if it was ever completed.

Comment: The PHP's PDO manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php only uses the non named parameters (?)

Comment: That is not a stored procedure but a regular Select Query in first example

Comment: The first example is a INSERT query not a CALL statement to a SP.. There are SP call's in the document you just have to find them.

Comment: So it seems that was never fixed or addressed. I just like the ability to be able to modify queries outside my PHP code. Also is there any numbers as fare as stored procedure and prepared statements goes